# HOW CAN I CORRECT THIS SQLITE SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: sql, sqlite

IN MY EMPLOYEE TABLE COLUMN "HIREDATE" HAS (DATETIME) FORMAT AND I AM GETTING ERROR WHEN I TRY RETRIEVE THE DATA BY THIS QUERY BELOW:

SELECT FirstName, HireDate FROM employees
WHERE HireDate ('2002-08-14 00:00:00'')

I AM GETTING AN ERROR IN SQLITE.

Execution finished with errors.
Result: unrecognized token: "'2002-08-14 00:00:00'') "
At line 1:
SELECT FirstName, HireDate FROM employees
--SELECT HireDate FROM employees
WHERE HireDate (

Comment: What do you expect from `WHERE HireDate ('2002-08-14 00:00:00'')`?

Comment: Typo?  Looks like you're missing an `=` in your `WHERE` clause.  (Potentially among other typos...)

Comment: I EXPECT ALL THE DATES FROM YEAR 2002.

Comment: Then what is the point of `'2002-08-14 00:00:00'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT FirstName, HireDate FROM employees WHERE HireDate > '2002-08-14 00:00:00'
```